# How can i make a smooth camera transition in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have an endless Paralax effect background which i want to move when clicking a button. So basically i want to move my camera about 20 units to the left or right every time i click a button, i kinda achieved this already, but i want the transition to be smooth, now it is all happening between two frames, thanks for any help, I'm desperate.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveAmount = 19.2f;

    public void ButtonLeft ()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.Translate(-moveAmount,0,0);
    }

    public void ButtonRight ()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.Translate(moveAmount,0,0);
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Smooth transitions can be done with the Vector3.Lerp function.
You can find detailed documentation and usage examples in the [official Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).

Your process should be that you specify a target and a start position of the camera. Then you lerp the position of the camera on each Update() until you reach the target.

A similar answer can also be found on the [unity forums](https://answers.unity.com/questions/444978/c-smoothing-out-transformtranslate.html).

Have fun! :)

Comment: Thanks, i kind of got it moving, now i just have to figure it out how to activate it only if i press a button, but hopefully that won't take long.

Comment: I think of two ways. A more complicated one, you create a bool and a float, when you click the button you activate the bool and set the float as the final position of the camera. Then in the Update put "if (bool)" then move the camera slightly, and you wonder if the position is beyond to the float of final position. If it is, then turn off the bool, otherwise you do nothing and the update continues to move the camera. Otherwise, much much easier, you can use a Coroutine, which you activate from the button, and manage everything there, moving, how long you want it to take moving, etc..